# Creating A dynamic grid of input areas in Flashbuilder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I'm trying to make an application with flash builder that performs operations on square matrices. I take in the size of he matrix (n) but now, I am having difficulty figuring out how to generate an n by n grid of text inputs where the user can enter the matrix element values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, do just like Peter Hall said. Use DataGroup with tile layout.

```
    <s:DataGroup itemRenderer="Groups.DataGroupRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="5" verticalGap="5" requestedRowCount="3" requestedColumnCount="3"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>3</fx:String>
                <fx:String>4</fx:String>
                <fx:String>5</fx:String>
                <fx:String>6</fx:String>
                <fx:String>7</fx:String>
                <fx:String>8</fx:String>
                <fx:String>9</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:DataGroup>
```

And renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:TextInput text="{data}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Of course if you know Flex at least in basic level, you will know how to do it all dynamically.

Comment: Oh thanks. I did that but I can't seem to retrieve the contents of the TextInput. when i call getItemAt on the ArrayCollection, it returns an Object and it isn't allowing me convert the object back to a TextInput that I can call 'text' on

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I quite understand you. If you want to get, for example, middle `TextInput` value from 3x3 matrix, you just assign `id = "dp"` for `DataGroup` and write: `dp.dataProvider.getItemAt(5)` you should get String with text `"5"` in this example.

Comment: Your `DataGroup` will be dependent only on its `dataProvider` if you want to set some `TextInput` you change `dataProvider`, if you want to retrieve, you read from `dataProvider`. You don't have to do anything with `TextInput` directly.

Comment: OH wow! Lmao! Thanks. That's what I did the first time but the program kept crashing so I assumed it was wrong. Turned out I had a counter that I wasn't incrementing and that was what was crashing the program. What a fail! lol. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataGroup with a TileLayout.